# Filter a field not in the model in Graphene?

Tags: python, django, graphene-python

I have a model GroupCode that has a OneToOne to Rol, and i want to filter rol by one of the fields in GroupCode(GroupCode is the one with the OneToOneField), i have searched a little, but many examples and questions about this seem to mention how to filter found on the model, but not ones defined on the type, like enabled in this case, this is an example of my schema:

```
class RolType(ModelType):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        interfaces = [graphene.relay.Node]
        connection_class = CountableConnection
        permissions = ['security.view_group']
        filter_fields = {
            'name': ['exact', 'icontains', 'istartswith']
        }

    enabled = graphene.Boolean()

    def resolve_enabled(self, info):
        
        return f"{GroupCode.objects.get(group=self.id).enabled}"

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    rol = graphene.relay.Node.Field(RolType)
    roles = DjangoFilterConnectionField(RolType, enabled=graphene.Boolean())
```

Does anyone knows how to filter based on this enabled field?